# Calculus - Comparative Rates of Change

Tags: calculus

[image]
I am working on this problem but can't quite get the correct answer. My working:

The question asks for $\frac{dh}{dt}$ where $h = \frac{1}{2}a$ which can be caculated using $\frac{dh}{dt} = \frac{dV}{dh}/\frac{dV}{dt}$

if $ V = \frac{1}{3}\pi h^2 (3a-h)$, when $h=\frac{1}{2} a$
$V = \frac{5}{24}\pi a^3 $

$\frac{dV}{dh} = \frac{15}{24}\pi a^2$ (expressed in a)

$\frac{dV}{dh} / \frac{dV}{dt} $= $\frac{15}{24}\pi a^2/3 \pi a^3 = \frac{15}{72}a$ but the answer is $4a$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have $dh/dt=(dV/dh)/(dV/dt),$ which is upside-down.

   Correct is $dh/dt=(dV/dt)/(dV/dh).$
2. $dV/dh=(\pi/3) \cdot d(3ah^2-h^3)/dh=$ $(\pi/3)\cdot(6ah-3h^2).$

   When $h=a/2$ this is $(\pi/3)\cdot (3a^2-3a^2/4)=$ $(\pi)\cdot (a^2-a^2/4)=$ $3\pi a^2/4.$
3. So when $h=a/2$ we have $$(dh/dt)=(dV/dt)/(dV/dh)=(3\pi a^3)/(3\pi a^2/4)=4a.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for highlighting the clarification, and corrections in a number of places during differentiation, much appreciated.

Comment: Could I ask for a quick clarification on the intuition behind point one? Going back to it I can see - a change in time leads to a change in volume ($\frac{dV}{dt}$) while a change in volume leads to a change in height ($\frac{dh}{dV}$). So $\frac{dV}{dt} * \frac{dh}{dV} = \frac{dh}{dt}$?Then to get it into a workable form the denominator is inverted and division used instead of multiplication?

Comment: In some calculations we can treat terms like $dh, dt,dV$ as if they were non-zero numbers For example, in this Q, as $V$ and $h$ are strictly monotonic functions of $t.$